# SQL Join to the latest record in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This does not solve my problem
[SQL Join to the latest record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605160/sql-join-to-the-latest-record)

I want to join tables in such a way that it fetches only the latest record from one of the tables using MySQL and also count the read_reciept columns with specific value

The following are my datas.

Table_One:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Tom |
| 3 | Anna |

Table_two:

| ID | Visit ID | Date | read_reciept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2513 | 5/5/2001 | 1 |
| 1 | 84654 | 10/5/2012 | 1 |
| 1 | 454 | 4/20/2018 | 1 |
| 2 | 754 | 4/5/1999 | 0 |
| 2 | 654 | 8/8/2010 | 1 |
| 2 | 624 | 4/9/1982 | 1 |
| 3 | 7546 | 7/3/1997 | 0 |
| 3 | 246574 | 6/4/2015 | 1 |
| 3 | 15487 | 3/4/2017 | 1 |

Results needed after Join:

| ID | Name | Visit ID | Date | read_reciept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 454 | 4/20/2018 | 3 |
| 2 | Tom | 654 | 8/8/2010 | 2 |
| 3 | Anna | 246574 | 6/4/2015 | 2 |

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Also: voted to reopen, because the duplicate question was for pre-8.0. For 8.0 and later there's a much better option.

Comment: [Do any of these answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're up to an 8.0 release, you have two options:

1. [LATERAL JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html). Just a docs link, because it's less effficient and (for MySQL) more awkward to write.
2. Windowing function:

```
SELECT ID, Name,VisitID, Date
FROM (
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t2.VisitID, t2.Date,
        row_number() over (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t2.Date DESC) rn
    FROM Table_One t1
    INNER JOIN Table_Two t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
) t 
WHERE rn = 1
```

If you're on an older release, well condolences first of all. 5.7 and older don't even really qualify as a modern database, and hasn't for a long time. But [this is still possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35965649/3043).

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50605493/10498828 is the answer from the duplicate link that I proposed that you duplicated with your answer.

Comment: @forpas When the question was closed, it was pointing to a different question where the top answers (nearly 200 votes) still used the 5.7 way. I think there must have been another close vote with the other question that SO used instead.

Comment: I used another question as a duplicate link to close the question and tried to edit more (because there are several such questions). But you opened the question in less than 1 min after it was closed.

Comment: Hmm... having read through the other question, it's also referring to SQL Server rather than MySQL, and the top answer there still suggests APPLY vs row_number().

Comment: But holy cow: it's even the same sample data! This has to be a homework assignment, in which case `row_number()` might not be what the professor expects ( undergrad homework tends for want to join to a subquery instead).

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn I would also like to count the read_reciept columns when it has a specific value. I have updated the question can you please assist me with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an old version of mysql then try this :

Steps to do it :

First we need to get the latest date :

```
select ID, MAX(Date) as max_date, sum(read_reciept) as read_reciept
from Table_two
group by ID
```

Then we get the related `Visit_ID` and sum(read_reciept):

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Visit_ID, t.max_date, t.read_reciept
FROM Table_two a
INNER JOIN (
  select ID, MAX(Date) as max_date, sum(read_reciept) as read_reciept
  from Table_two
  group by ID
) as t on a.ID = t.ID and a.Date = t.max_date
```

And Finally we join our data using `INNER JOIN` to get the expected result

```
SELECT a.ID, b.Name, a.Visit_ID, a.Date, t.read_reciept
FROM Table_two a
INNER JOIN Table_One b on a.ID = b.ID
INNER JOIN (
   select ID, MAX(Date) as max_date, sum(read_reciept) as read_reciept
   from Table_two
 group by ID
) as t on a.ID = t.ID and a.Date = t.max_date
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vi9DevWW)

Comment: I would also like to count the read_reciept columns when it has a specific value.  I have updated the question. Can you please help me with it?

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you have a look

Comment: Can you update the demo, let me have a look, please!

Comment: Already updated it

Comment: Thanks, but when I adopted your solution for my large database I got a different result with @joel Coehoorn solution I got the expected result but without the read_reciept count.

Answer (score 0):

Use sub-query with `row_number` to get only the last row from that `table_two`.

```sql
select Table_One.ID, name, Visit_ID, date_
from Table_One
join (select ID, Visit_ID, date_, row_number() over (partition by id order by date_ desc) rn
      from Table_two) t2
on (t2.ID = Table_One.ID and t2.rn=1)
```

Here `row_number` will number row with the same `ID` based on order by `date` column.

Later during join we take only rows with the value being produced equal 1, which means in this case - oldest.